# Anti-phishing method for Thunderbird using filters?

Tags: thunderbird, phishing

I would like to create a Thunderbird filter that moves all messages into a directory `phishing` if the  Subject matches `Foobar` and if and only if they're not from `Foobar.net` (as determined by the end of the From: address)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is currently no option for `does not end with`, the closest might be the filter shown below. The `@` symbol should be sufficient to ensure that addresses such as @NotReally.Foobar.net are caught, but would miss @Foobar.net.com.

That said, the `From` line is often misleading, since so many phishing emails use [spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing): that address is untrustworthy. A filter might be of some use, but expect 'leakage' no matter what you do.

[image: FooFilter]

Comment: damn, I really wanted regex capability in there, guess it's not possible.

Comment: Regex seems to be possible with the [FiltaQuilla plugin](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/)

Comment: To protect against spoofing, the [DKIM Verifier plugin](https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/dkim-verifier/) can be used.